# How to find bounds of integration in finding CDF of $XY$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Suppose you had $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}1/4,&0<X<2, 0 <Y<X^3 \\0,& \text{otherwise}   \end{cases}$

How would you find a CDF for $Z=XY$?

I know it's of the form

$$F_Z(z) = P(XY \leq z) = \iint_{\{(x,y):xy\leq z\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)~dx~dy$$

I'm just a bit unclear on how to set up the bounds of the integral.

Comment: Draw a picture and divide the integral by x=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $Y<X^3$ and $XY<z \implies Y<z/X$; i.e., $Y < \min\{X^3,z/X\}$.

For $X^3<z/X$, or $X < z^{1/4}$, we have
$$Y < \min\{X^3,z/X\} = X^3;$$
otherwise
$$Y < \min\{X^3,z/X\} = z/X.$$
Consequently,

$$\Pr\{XY <z\} = \int_{0}^{z^{1/4}}\int_{0}^{x^3}\frac{1}{4}dy\,dx + \int_{z^{1/4}}^{2}\int_{0}^{z/x}\frac{1}{4}dy\,dx,$$
where $0 < z < 16$.

Comment: I don't think I understand your use of min. What is min telling us about the limits?

Comment: @HumptyDumpty Note that $Y < X^3$ **and** $Y < z/X$. For $X < z^{1/4}$, $X^3 < z/X$. Therefore, $Y < X^3< z/X$. So $0 < Y < X^3$ dictates the integration limits. Similar arguments can be used regarding other integration limits.

Comment: @HumptyDumpty  If $Y< X^3$ and $Y<z/X$ then $Y<\min\{X^3,z/X\}$.   So $$\mathsf P(XY<z)=\int_0^2\int_0^{\min\{x^3, z/x\}} \tfrac 14~\mathsf dy~\mathsf dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2}{1 \over 4}
{\bracks{0 < z/x < x^{3}} \over \verts{x}}\,\dd x & =
{1 \over 4}\bracks{z > 0}
\int_{0}^{2}{\bracks{x > z^{1/4}} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\bracks{z > 0}\bracks{z^{1/4} < 2}\int_{z^{1/4}}^{2}
{\dd x\over x}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\bracks{0 < z < 16}\ln\pars{2 \over z^{1/4}}
\end{align}

[image]